# Can not handle user pagination with `GridLayoutManager`

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I searched all day but cant find answer. I have `RecyclerView` and I must use `GridLayoutManager` as layoutManager. But when I want to use pagination on this `RecyclerView` this pagination at all time. `visibleItemCount` always equals `totalItemCount`,but when I use `LinearLayout` everything working fine. But I need `GridlayoutManager`. So Can anyone help me?

```
public class CategoryChildrenFragment extends BasicFragment implements CategoryChildrenFragmentView, CategoryChildrenAdapter.CategoryChildrenListener, CategoryProductsAdapter.CategoryProductListener {

@BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;



@BindView(R.id.recyclerViewProducts)
RecyclerView mRecyclerViewProducts;



@BindView(R.id.text_view_category_name)
TextView mTextViewCategoryName;


@Inject
Navigator mNavigator;


@InjectPresenter
CategoryChildrenFragmentPresenter mPresenter;


private  List<CategoryObject> mCategories;
private  List<CategoryProduct> products;
private  CategoryObject mCategory;
GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
private int categoryId = 0;
private int page = 0;
private int mDisplayWidth = 1020;
private String searchText = "";
private CategoryProductsAdapter mAdapterProducts;
private CategoriesResponse mResponse;
private int totalItemCount = 0;
private boolean isLastPage = false;
private boolean isLoading = false;


@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public CategoryChildrenFragment(CategoryObject categoryObject,List<CategoryObject> categories) {
    this.mCategory = categoryObject;
    this.mCategories = categories;
}





private void initView(View view) {
    ButterKnife.bind(this,view);


    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
     mDisplayWidth = size.x;

    List<CategoryObject> selectedList = new LinkedList<>();


    if (null != mCategory) {
        mTextViewCategoryName.setText(mCategory.getName());

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


        if (mCategory.getId() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i <mCategories.size(); i++) {
                if (mCategory.getId() == mCategories.get(i).getParentId()) {
                    selectedList.add(mCategories.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            products = new LinkedList<>();

            categoryId = 0;

            layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);

            mRecyclerViewProducts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            mRecyclerViewProducts.setAdapter(mAdapterProducts = new CategoryProductsAdapter(products,this, (int) (mDisplayWidth/2.27),getContext()));
            mRecyclerViewProducts.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewOnScrollListener);
            getLoadingDialog().showDialog(getFragmentManager());
            mPresenter.GET_ALL_BY_PARENT_CATEGORY(getAccessToken(),searchText,categoryId,page, 20);
        }

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CategoryChildrenAdapter(selectedList,this));
    }
}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_childs, container, false);
    initView(view);
    return view;
}





@Override
public void onChildrenClicked(CategoryObject categoryObject) {
    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    products = new LinkedList<>();

    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);

    categoryId = categoryObject.getId();

    mTextViewCategoryName.setText(categoryObject.getName());

    mRecyclerViewProducts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerViewProducts.setAdapter(mAdapterProducts = new CategoryProductsAdapter(products,this, (int) (mDisplayWidth/2.27),getContext()));
    mRecyclerViewProducts.addOnScrollListener(recyclerViewOnScrollListener);
    getLoadingDialog().showDialog(getFragmentManager());
    mPresenter.GET_ALL_BY_PARENT_CATEGORY(getAccessToken(),searchText,categoryId,page,20);

}




@Override
public void initProducts(CategoriesResponse response) {
    this.mResponse = response;
    this.products.addAll(response.getList());
    mAdapterProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();
    isLoading = false;
}



@Override
public void stopProgressBar() {
    getLoadingDialog().hideDialog();
}



@Override
public void onProductClicked(CategoryProduct categoryProduct) {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setProductId(categoryProduct.getId());
    product.setPhotos(categoryProduct.getPhotos());

    mNavigator.toProductActivity(getContext(),product);

}



@Override
public void onAddToCard(CategoryProduct product) {
    mNavigator.toAddTOCardDialogFragment(getFragmentManager(),product);
}




private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener recyclerViewOnScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {


    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    }




    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (null != mResponse && 0 != mResponse.getAllCount() && totalItemCount == mResponse.getAllCount()) {
            isLastPage = true;
        }


        if (!isLoading && !isLastPage) {
            if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount && firstVisibleItemPosition > 0 &&  totalItemCount <  mResponse.getAllCount()) {
                page = page + 1;
                isLoading = true;
                mPresenter.GET_ALL_BY_PARENT_CATEGORY(getAccessToken(),searchText,categoryId,page,20);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally guys I found a solution.My recyclerview was inside a NestedScrollview so I cant get right things for scrollListener.I changed NestedScroll to LinearLayout everything is cool.So conculusion do not put recyclerview inside scrollview if you want to listen scroll of recyclerview

Answer (score 2):

use findLastVisibleItemPosition() and findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() functions for GridLayoutManager:

```
private val recyclerViewOnScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as GridLayoutManager
        val visibleItemCount = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
    }
}
```